# mysql optimization for a lot of data

Tags: mysql, optimization

I would like your opinions on a db schema I will be creating.
The db will hold data from different languages. Daily the inserts will be around 30.000  - 50.000, with heavy reads.
I can have just 6 tables holding the data for every language or I can create 6 different tables for each language.
Will the second option be more efficient for heavy reads? What other techniques do you suggest, to help the system's
performance (data partitioning etc)?

Thanks

Comment: If the data types match, don't create 6 different tables (without trying some sort of partitioning first).  What are the columns/types you have in this table?  When you say "heavy reads", how heavy?

Comment: Do the inserts all take place at the same time, or are they done throughout the day?

Comment: At crontab Throughout the day

At Brad
The 6 tables I mention is the bare minimum in order to have the db normalized. I expect to have from 500 - 1000 q/sec with some queries joining 3 tables

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this blog post might be useful:

http://20bits.com/articles/10-tips-for-optimizing-mysql-queries-that-dont-suck/

Oh yes and another tip... Don't use 6 tables!